# Teradata version support LDAP connection

Tags: ldap, teradata

Do all Teradata versions support LDAP connections, if not from which version the LDAP was implemented?

Regards,

Comment: I believe that was V2R6.0 (which would be TD 11.0 in the current numbering scheme) - roughly 15 years ago.

Comment: Thank you Fred, have you any articles discribe this ( I would to confirme that is not implemented only for TD17)

Comment: Check the *Security Administration* manual, the oldest version available online is TD15: https://docs.teradata.com/r/AhOAsYfub6iLoEGgDSmXOQ/wGybJvPbynuXlfIUKi2PJQ